# Executing terminal commands from PHP with sudo rights

Tags: php

I want to start a Python script from inside PHP code but i can't get the script to run with sudo rights. I'm running a LAMP installation with PHP 7.1 and the script needs to download and create temporary files.

I have tried putting the script in `sudoers` like this `www-data ALL=(root) NOPASSWD: /var/www/html/smuggler/process-data.py` and with some other variation of this i found online, but it didn't work. I also tried to set the rights to the python file itself using `chmod` but that didn't work either.
Everything i found online didn't work.

The only way it works is when i run it from the terminal as sudo.

I'd appreciate if someone could help me. Thanks.

Comment: I have to strongly advise against giving anything sudo rights.

Comment: @Derek It is very unlikely that someone would be able to insert malicious code inside this script since the files its downloading are from a secure server and do not contain any user input. However, how would you suggest i go about this otherwise?

Comment: you cant run that script with the root user?

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix I seem not to be able to run it as root...i tried and i can't even download the files using just PHP because i get Permission denied everytime...i might have did something wrong while setting up my development server today. If i run the PHP or Pyrhon code from the terminal as root everything works but when i access the pages from the browser i get a Permission denied error